# Pass a string in payload of POST

Tags: spring, api, rest, http

Usually we pass key-value pair in JSON payload for POST/PUT request. Is it possible to pass a sting only ex:
[image]

If so what do we set the object for @RequestBody? Would it be String type or JSONObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is setting

```
@PutMapping(value = "/test/{id}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
String updateInfo(@RequestHeader(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody String payload){...}
```

and passing the string payload by escacping the double quotes

```
updateInfo(token, id, "\"TEST\"");
```

Answer (score 2):

I did this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "businessdate", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public void postBusinessDate(@RequestBody String businessDate) throws IOException, InterruptedException, SQLException {
    businessDateService.updateBusinessDate(LocalDate.parse(businessDate));
}
```

and passed this:

[image]

Comment: I dont want to pass it as PLAIN_TEXT, I wanted to pass it as JSON type

Comment: What did you try, anything?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It would be a String. Even though you choose content type as application/json

[image]